# Deforming the brim of a woman's summer hat or cowboy hat in a natural looking fashion?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation, surface-deform

I would like to create some simple cartoonish summer hats like:

[image]

[image]

The simplest basic model of this type of hat can be made simply by starting with a plane, insetting it, then extruding the inset, marking the crease to around 0.4, and applying a subdivision and solidify modifier:

[image]

Proportions and the rounding of the dome can then easily be shaped with crease settings or scaling.

However, the part I can't figure out a good or effective solution for is the natural brim deformation that these hats tend to get.

I presume a good solution might also allow a method for making the brim of a cowboy hat:

[image]

The basic point in both is you want to deform the brim without creating new material or changing the basic surface area of the brim (which might otherwise make it look distorted and unnatural).

Ideally I would like to do it non-destructively with modifiers but I presume that's not likely possible.

Is cloth simulation the solution here? eg. For the women's summer hat could I somehow apply a different weight to the four brim vertexes and thus nondestructively let them sag differently because of it? I am not knowledgeable on cloth simulations, so if this will work please provide any settings I can try.

The only thing I can think of that I know is to apply a lattice or apply my existing modifiers then sculp it but those are not really ideal. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You could begin with a cylinder that you extrude and subdivide:

[image]

Then you can deform, with the *Proportional Editing* on, or with a *Lattice*:

[image]

At the end, give it a *Solidify* modifier and apply it:

[image]